# Trying to see how method is called ie. if $('.test') or $('.test').hide() , if first one return element if second return object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class

I am trying to recreate the $() selector and so far all is well. One thing I am hung up on is how to return an element rather than the object if no method is being called.

For example:

I have a function

```
function $(selector){

return new DomEl(selector); //this would be the simialr ot the jquer object that has all methods

}
```

The above allows me to call a methods on the element like so:

`$('#test').hide();`

But if I just use the function without calling any class like so: $('#test')

I want it to return the element:

```
return document.querySelector(selector)
```

So my question is how can I detect how the $() function is being called and whether or not it is being called with a class method to be called upon it ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot predict what's going to happen in the future. Your function returns a value synchronously, and then it's up to the developer to decide whether they will call methods on it eventually. You _could_ extend the prototype of DOM elements, but that would probably not be the best idea (And it's a good thing jQuery didn't go that way - they always return a jQuery object). On a side note, `querySelectorAll` would be more accurate to select multiple elements, but that is up to your needs

Comment: Okay thanks for some reason I thought Jquery somehow did this. Seems as if they don't. And yeah I 'm actually using querySelecorAll inside of my constructor for my Jquery like class(domEl). Thanks for clearing this up or I would have went down even more of a rabbit whole. I guess I'll just use querySelector/All when I need to return an element/s

Comment: Either that, or do like jQuery and have a [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) method on your DomEl class, allowing you to do `$('#text').get() // Array containing the elements` or `$('#text').get(0) // A single DOM element`